# How to install RTL8812BU Wifi driver for Realtek (0bda:b812) on 5.11 kernel while having iwlwifi-backport (Ubuntu 21.04)

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel, iwlwifi, realtek-wireless

My Dell laptop came with a Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi Network adapter that is currently faulty both in Ubuntu 21.04 and Windows 10 (I dual boot). I am using iwlwifi-backport and now the adapter works, although not on every boot and it dissappears at some point. While I am waiting for a new wifi card, I have got a USB WiFi adapter from a friend, no idea about the model, it only has "AC 1300" on it.

lsusb:

`Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL88x2bu [AC1200 Techkey]`

So I guess I need a 8812bu or 88x2bu driver, I tried several drivers I found, i.e. https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver or https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu.
In all cases when I could install the module, modprobe fails to load it and dmesg gets flooded by this kind of message:

```
[Sa Sep 25 14:44:02 2021] 88x2bu: disagrees about version of symbol __cfg80211_alloc_event_skb
[Sa Sep 25 14:44:02 2021] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol __cfg80211_alloc_event_skb (err -22)
[Sa Sep 25 14:44:02 2021] 88x2bu: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_register
[Sa Sep 25 14:44:02 2021] 88x2bu: Unknown symbol wiphy_register (err -22)
[Sa Sep 25 14:44:02 2021] 88x2bu: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_remain_on_channel_expired
```

I believe I have correct linux headers installed:

```
uname -r
5.11.0-36-generic
```

```
dpkg -l linux-headers-5.11*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                            Version      Architecture Description
+++-===============================-============-============-=========================================================
ii  linux-headers-5.11.0-36         5.11.0-36.40 all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.11.0
ii  linux-headers-5.11.0-36-generic 5.11.0-36.40 amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

I found a bug suggesting iwlwifi-backport could be breaking the driver: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205573

How should I proceed to get the adapter to work?

Comment: Uninstalling the iwlwifi backports is the only way to fix

Comment: @Jeremy31 how can I do it?